# Having issues deleting Anaconda on my Mac

Tags: linux, macos, anaconda

I'm trying to completely uninstall Anaconda on my Mac but I'm running into issues removing the files. The Anaconda files were saved in ~/opt and when I try to remove it using `$ sudo rm -rf /opt` I get this error: `rm: /opt: Read-only file system` so I try remounting it by doing: `mount -o remount,rw /opt` and I get this error: `mount: /opt: unknown special file or file system.`

I've also tried using commands like unmount as well, and I've had no success... If someone could help me, I would really apprecite it!

Comment: The Anaconda files are in `~/opt` (in your user directory), but the commands in your question are trying to remove `/opt` from the root directory of the filesystem...

Answer (score 0):

Instructions to remove Anaconda are given here. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

You need to run:  rm -rf ~/anaconda3

There are other instructions for a complete uninstall given in the link above.